# Tensor Product in Q#

Tags: programming, q#, linear-algebra

Does anyone know how you can obtain a new state `|z>` from two pre-existing states `|x>` and `|y>` using the Tensor product in `Q#`? i.e. `|z> = |x> ⊗|y>` ?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit: for clarity, the states that I am working with are

$|x\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sum^{3}_{j=0} \sin \frac{\pi (j + 0.5)}{4} |j\rangle$

$|y\rangle = \sum^{1}_{i=0} b_i |i\rangle$

where the $b_i$'s are just real numbers.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by obtaining a "new state"? What do you want to do with these qubits? In Q# you are working with `Qubit` objects, not states. So if you have two `Qubit` objects and they are not entangled, then essentially they are already in a tensor product state.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your reply! So I used two `Qubit` objects : `Qubit[2]` and `Qubit[1]` and used the `PrepareArbitraryState` operation in order to map those qubits to the states `|x>` and `|y>` (I edited the question so you can see how my states look like). Now I want to encode in a new variable of type `Qubit[]` the result of the tensor product between `|x>` and `|y>`.

Comment: Hi Martin, I've posted an answer below, hopefully that helps to clarify. You could also make a new `Qubit[3]` array and put all three qubits in there. Just putting them in an array is enough, you don't need to do anything special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of `Qubit` objects, and you prepare the individual qubits into arbitrary states, then the array effectively contains the tensor product of all of the original qubits.

To quickly illustrate what I mean:

```
using (qubits = Qubit[2]) {
    // do something to prepare qubits[0] individually
    // do something to prepare qubits[1] individually

    // now the state of "qubits" is the tensor product of the two
    // individual qubit states that you prepared
}
```

This also generalizes if you're preparing groups of qubits within the array that you allocated.